# How to take key value pairs and turn them into an array of objects using JMESPath

Tags: json, normalization, jmespath

I'm looking to change the data structure of a 3rd party API using JMESPath and haven't been able to figure out how to take a single object of key-value pairs and restructure this to an array of objects, each containing key-value pairs.

I've gone through all of the [JMESPath docs](http://jmespath.org/specification.html) and [examples](http://jmespath.org/examples.html) without finding the specific data structure I've been working with. I've tried using the [keys(@)](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#keys) and [values(@)](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#values) built-in functions to grab the key and values of these pairs, but haven't been able to join them together into a single array.

Here is my original JSON data

```
{
"time": 32,
    "terms": {
        "192.168.10.121": 84,
        "154.223.10.121": 12,
        "112.149.10.121": 6
    }
}
```

I'm trying to convert the above JSON data to the following strucutre using JMESPath.

```
{
"data": [
    { "ip_address": "192.168.10.121", "count": 84 },
    { "ip_address": "154.223.10.121", "count": 12 },
    { "ip_address": "112.149.10.121", "count": 6 }
]}
```

I've been able to create an array of the keys or an array of values, but not able to create the array of objects containing key-value pairs.
`terms.{ data: keys(@)}`
`terms.{ data: values(@)}`

Result when using `terms.{ data: keys(@)}`

```
{
"data": [
    "192.168.10.121",
    "154.223.10.121",
    "112.149.10.121"
]}
```

Result when using `terms.{ data: values(@)}`

```
{
"data": [
    84,
    12,
    6
]}
```

Those two functions seem like the only functions I can use to pull the keys and values from an object containing key-value pairs not originally within an array. From what I can tell, I'm not able to combine both of those functions to output a single array like my example above.

I'm not even sure this is possible using JMESPath. Any expert opinion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

### Context

- jmespath query language
- how to re-normalize data from one structure (schema) to another
- how to effectively iterate and filter on object properties (name-value pairs)

### Pitfalls

- Generally speaking, jmespath is highly flexible in iterating sequentially-indexed arrays, but much less flexible in iterating over object properties
- Most transformations with jmespath become **extremely cumbersome** when the goal is to iterate over object properties
- Usually you can produce any arbitrary output in jmespath if you are willing to "manually construct" the output by hand ... this is usually the trade-off when dealing with iterating over object properties (aka name-value pairs)

### Example

> Given the following original dataset ...

```
{"time": 32,
    "terms": {
        "192.168.10.121": 84,
        "154.223.10.121": 12,
        "112.149.10.121": 6
    }
}
```

> ... the following jmespath query ...

```
{"data": [
  { "ip_address": @.terms|keys(@)[0], "count": @.terms|values(@)[0] }
  ,{ "ip_address": @.terms|keys(@)[1], "count": @.terms|values(@)[1] }
  ,{ "ip_address": @.terms|keys(@)[2], "count": @.terms|values(@)[2] }
]}
```

> ... produces the following result

```
{"data": [
    { "ip_address": "192.168.10.121", "count": 84 },
    { "ip_address": "154.223.10.121", "count": 12 },
    { "ip_address": "112.149.10.121", "count": 6 }
]}
```